# Meaning of 'e veri' in a fifteenth century text

Tags: translation, word-meaning

I'm trying to understand the following. It's from a fifteenth century text.

> Furono istorie dieci tutti in casamenti colla ragione che l'occhio li
>   misura e veri in modo tale, stando remoti da essi appariscano
>   rilevati.

I don't understand what the meaning of 'e veri' is. I'd appreciate any help (in either English or Italian).

---

You can find a sample of the text [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=7JsRPSCkzSoC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=Furono+istorie+dieci+tutti+in+casamenti&source=bl&ots=c9TVAJZG6r&sig=xasDmxwrHqJ3mJa9YCYkCNHNDlY&hl=it&sa=X&ei=5Mg2VL3RLIbAObuFgfgG&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Furono%20istorie%20dieci%20tutti%20in%20casamenti&f=false).

Comment: *u* and *v* were often typeset with the same letter (*v*) so it your text may be *e veri*. Note also that *rileuati* at the end must be *rilevati*. However I don't understand that usage of *e veri* in that context.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the text in question is about architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si tratta di una frase presa da un'opera incompiuta di un architetto e scultore vissuto a cavallo tra il XIV e il XV secolo, Lorenzo Ghiberti. Proprio in quel periodo si incomincia a parlare di prospettiva e della proprietà che hanno gli oggetti che allontanandosi sembrano più piccoli all'osservatore.

Io parafraserei cosi:

Erano dieci raffigurazioni (istoriare vuol dire "Adornare una superficie con la raffigurazione (in pittura, scultura, ecc.) di immagini relative a fatti storici o sacri o leggendarî" - Treccani) in costruzioni con l'impression che danno all'occhio  e talmente verosimili tanto che, allontanandosi da esse, sembravano sollevati (in rilievo)

Quindi 'e ueri' significherebbe 'verosimili'

Answer (score 3):

It's worth quoting [a modern edition](https://books.google.it/books?id=kbcpj4QnX5UC&pg=PR34): «li misura, e veri in modo tale, [che]». So, as laika says, you can just read it as "e" conjunction + "veri" adjective, attribute of the object "li".

Secondo me, però, la frase ha una chiara influenza latina. La mia prima impressione qui è che "e" non stia per la congiunzione moderna, ma per il latino *et*, o *etiam*. Sarebbe quindi un secondo rafforzativo di "veri", che in italiano parlato uno tradurrebbe "tanto ma tanto veri" o simile. Oppure, potrebbe anche avere un sapore correlativo, stando per "etiam... quod". In entrambi i casi la traduzione sarebbe la stessa offerta da laika, ma forse interessa sapere come arrivarci.

Sorry for switching languages, it's hard for me to talk of Latin in English.

Answer (score 2):

It could be "veri" = plural of "vero" (true).

Guessing from the context, that looks a narration from a painter: 
"and so much realistic (that) when you are far from them they look protruding".

But myself I found difficult the first part.